# How to delete Ads by AddFreeApp?

Tags: virus, malware

I really need help, I downloaded a software that installed this malware to my computer.. Now, I used adwcleaner,hitmanpro,malwarebytes and all of those found something but that wasn't it.. When I got to extensions there is no adfreeapp in there, just the regular stuff.. In the program files there is no adfreeapp program to uninstall.. But it still pops up whenever I open almost any site.. Sometimes it even crashes my browser.. Thanks. :)

Comment: Have you tried this way? http://malwaretips.com/blogs/adfreeapp-virus-removal/

Comment: Like I said, I've tried every step and it still didn't work but the virus doesn't show up as an extension or an actual program in the "add or remove programs" .. That's pretty weird..

Comment: What browser is affected? IE, Firefox, Chrome? or All?

Comment: What OS are you using? Assuming you are using Windows...have you run the antivirus and malware scans in Safe Mode with the Internet disconnected?

Comment: I use Google Chrome on Windows 7..

Comment: And no, I haven't tried it in Safe Mode without internet..

Comment: Ok, I'm doing the SPYHunter scan and it found like 102 threats and all of them are malware.. I hope those are (or at least one of those is) adfreeapp because it's starting to drive me crazy.. It pops up one EVERY SINGLE tab I open and it crashes my Chrome..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a link to 2 ways to remove this app.

http://computervirusremovalfixer.blogspot.ca/2015/06/guide-to-remove-addfreeapp-effectively.html

I have not had this problem so cannot verify that this will work.
Good luck.